# What environment was Coherent developed with?

Tags: unix

[Coherent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_(operating_system)) was a Unix clone for IBM compatibles Mark Williams Company produced and sold in the 1980s and early 1990s.

What environment and tools was Coherent developed with? Was it cross-developed on another Unix system?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I emailed this question to [Steve Ness](http://www.nesssoftware.com), who [worked at Mark Williams Company](http://www.nesssoftware.com/home/mwc) from 1977 through 1995 on Coherent and other projects. This is his answer, which I share with permission:

> Mark Williams Co. used a PDP-11 as development platform before COHERENT came up, once COHERENT booted all development shifted quickly to COHERENT-based.
>
> [...]
>
> MWC never had any Unix machine in-house.  Some of the developers had previously used Unix at Waterloo.

Many thanks to Steve Ness for the information.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this article](https://www.osnews.com/story/28443/coherent-unix-clone-goes-open-source/) and a few others around the net, Coherent was originally written on and for the DEC PDP -11. It was then ported to other processors, including x86.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The article says Coherent was originally developed *for* the PDP-11, but leaves out whether it was developed *on* the PDP-11. Are there sources confirming the latter?

Comment: Based on https://groups.google.com/g/alt.folklore.computers/c/_ZaYeY46eb4/m/5B41Uym6d4QJ, an argument could be made that development started on a PDP-7 as AT&T Unix, but I am hesitant to say that with any more certainty than Dennis Ritchie had.

Comment: Having said that, I'd be surprised if Mark Williams Co had anything other than a PDP-11 to do development on.